# Abstract Factory Pattern implemented as Interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, factory

I'm curious about abstract factory pattern. From Java 8 we have default methods, does it mean that we can replace our abstract classes to interfaces? The one downside which I can see it's a case when we need non-static / final field. We can't do it interface. Could you give me some examples (except this one I listed) when old-fashion factories has more advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You technically can, but you shouldn't.

The default implementation on an interface is a tool with a few very specific purposes- primarily, for adding functionality to an interface which very likely has been implemented by clients outside of your control, or for an interface which has been implemented repeatedly, where the default implementation would be onerous to re-implement.

They are *not* intended as a replacement (or even supplement) to abstract classes, when you are extending from some common parent's behavior.

Now, that said, the abstract factory *pattern* has little to do with Java's use of the abstract keyword.  The abstract factory pattern is about hiding (or abstracting away) the concrete factory implementation a given client is actually using to produce an object.  What the factory's factory methods are defined as returning may be a concrete class, an abstract class, or an interface.

So, for example-

Suppose you have some class, GuiPainter.  It has a method, #paintWindow.

Under the covers, you've introduced a Window, with OS specific implementations like AppleWindow, AndroidWindow, UbunutuWindow (and etc).  Each Window implementation varies a little in how it needs to be constructed.

One approach would be to construct GuiPainter with an AppleWindowFactory, an AndroidWindowFactory, an UbuntuWindowFactory (and etc), along with a means to find the OS and decide which factory to use.  However, all GuiPainter really wants is any instance of Window- it has no other OS-specific knowledge.

So, instead, we introduce a WindowFactory, which returns a Window.  WindowFactory is a Factory which has that knowledge of discovering the OS and deciding which of the concrete Window factories to use- abstracting that responsibility away from GuiPainter.

Window itself might be a concrete class with a single implementation and just configuration difference based on OS. It might be an abstract class with OS-specific implementations (like AppleWindow, AndroidWindow, etc).  It might even be an Interface which is implemented anonymously by the factories.  What Window *is* doesn't change that the client no longer has to worry about OS specific nonsense to get the window it wants.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does, but I can do it everything while using interfaces instead of abstract class and the question was, why I shouldn't do it? I can create the same abstraction with interface. "They are not intended" - why?

Comment: TL;DR: https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java

In very practical terms, stateless classes and interfaces with default implementations are often interchangeable.  That said, interfaces with default implementations allow you to cut yourself in ways stateless classes don't (such as via a class implementing two interfaces with the same method definition, but both providing default implementations), and will still have to be instantiated either anonymously or as part of whatever the factory returns.

You can drive nails in with a screwdriver, but it's easier with a hammer :)

Comment: Alright I see differences now, thanks for a link and your explanation too :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's a widely used technique.

You'll often stumble upon public `interfaces`, e.g:

```
public interface Cache<K, V> {
    public Optional<V> get(K k);
    public V put(K k, V v);
    // ...
}
```

and **hidden** ( = `package-private` or nested `private` ) implementations.

```
class SoftCache<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, SoftReference<V> dataMap;
    // ...
}
class WeakCache<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, WeakReference<V> dataMap;
    // ...
}
```

There is no need to be multiple implementations, the pattern is valid and fully applicable even with just one sub-class.

---

Your classes using your caching system **do not care** about the implementation details. They only care about the behavior exposed, and this is describable **very well** through an `interface`.

You are talking about `default` and `factory` methods, but they really differ from each other, and I feel you are mixing things up a little bit.

`default` methods [were mostly added](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) because if you have 20 classes implementing `MyInterface` and you add a method within your interface, it'd be an extremely painful job to implement a behavior (which is usually the same across all classes) in 20 different places.

I feel `Java 8/9+` is heavily going towards this pattern : factory methods within `interfaces`. Take as example the API `Set.of(...)`, `Map.of(...)`, and more.

Take `java.util.Stream<T>` as an example.

You usually use it this way (for Objects):

```
private Stream<Element> stream;
```

or

```
private IntStream intStream;
```

You do not care whether an element you are currently having is a `Head` element, an `OfRef` or anything else.

These are hidden details, unreachable from your code.

Yet, the `interface` `Stream<T>` **does** expose the factory method `of` (among others):

```
/**
 * Returns a sequential {@code Stream} containing a single element.
 *
 * @param t the single element
 * @param <T> the type of stream elements
 * @return a singleton sequential stream
 */
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Streams.StreamBuilderImpl<>(t), false);
}
```

There is nothing wrong in having your `interface` expose factory methods instead of `abstract` classes, but at the end of the day it depends entirely on you and how you feel more comfortable doing things.

It's also to be noted that `java` usually uses this pattern:

```
interface > abstract class > other classes
```

See also `java.util.Collection<E>` and its sub-classes.